# How can I install SharpDX for my project?

Tags: sharpdx

Unfortunately, as an experienced developer, I can not find the download link for SharpDX's binary files on SharpDX's download page here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/4.2.0

I am very surprised about the high download numbers.

How do I actually download/install this?

Comment: You've linked to a package manager website. Presumably you tried using that package manager to install the package?

Answer (score 2):

On the right hand side of the page is a list of actions.
On the bottom, it says "Download Package".
It prompts a download of the nuget package, which I believe is what you want.

This is the link:
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/SharpDX/4.2.0

**About Nuget:**
To use a nuget package, you need a nuget package manager.
Alternatively, you can open them with a compression software (WinRar, WinZip, 7Zip, etc) and extract the files manually.

Nuget is a standard for library distribution.
The nuget package managers does the heavy lifting for you when you want to add or update external libraries.
This removes the need for manual management of those libraries, which could be quite a pain for some more complex setups.

It's integrated in the last few Visual Studio versions, otherwise you can download the manager [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager).
I don't have much experience with other IDE's and nuget.

Comment: Hi! Given the nature of the question, I'd add a bit explaining what to do with the package once you get it. Like, is nuget already installed? etc. :)

Comment: True. I tend to forget that apart from the OP, other people might have the same issue. I'll expand a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution is to unzip this nuget package by simply renaming it to a zip file.